# how to parse json by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

```
var json ='{
 "maps":{

  "map":[
     {
        "name":"acb bank",
        "langName":"acb bank",
        "address":"distric 7",
        "coordinate":"10.041285568128918,105.79299676260861"
     },
     {
        "name":"food store",
        "langName":"vietnam food",
        "address":"distric 8",
        "coordinate":"10.06196571359739,105.78313580009822"
     }
  ]
 }
}';

var getdata = JSON.stringify(json);

for(var i=0; i < getdata.length; i++){
    document.write(getdata.maps.map[i].name);
}
```

i can't get name or coordinate...Please help me parse to it.

Answer (score 0):

To Parse JSON in JS you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

You are probably looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6CyZG/1/)

```
var json ={
 "maps":{
     "map":[
         {
            "name":"acb bank",
            "langName":"acb bank",
            "address":"distric 7",
            "coordinate":"10.041285568128918,105.79299676260861"
         },
         {
            "name":"food store",
            "langName":"vietnam food",
            "address":"distric 8",
            "coordinate":"10.06196571359739,105.78313580009822"
         }
      ]
     }
    };

     var data = json.maps.map;
     for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) 
         document.write(data[i].name);
```

Comment: thank you!, the first time i post question. :D

Comment: No Problem. Just remember to accept whose ever answer worked for you. So future users will have a solution to try.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line breaks in your string. Also, remove the comma in coordinate. Also, use:

```
JSON.parse(json);
```

Edit: Actually, it seems like you actually wanted to know how to properly stringify an object into json. In that case, remove the two single quotes at the start and end of your object.